# How to remove a wifi hostspot from the windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, hotspot

I have created a hotspot with my windows 7, But I don't know how to remove that. any one please help me to remove this?

here is the screen shot: ( need to remove the Hotpost)

[image: need to remove Hotpot]

Comment: In a `cmd` shell run `netsh wlan delete profile name="Hotspot"`